# Visual Studio Linux unit tests

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, googletest

We have a C++ Linux project in Visual Studio that we build and run remotely on a Docker container. I am beginning to write unit tests for the project using Google Test (not tied to this framework) which I also want to run remotely. Unfortunately the tests are run locally which doesn't suit what I am trying to achieve. Does anyone know if this can be done with any test framework for C++ and if so could you point me to relevant docs etc?

I know I can create another standard Linux project containing the tests which I can run remotely but then I lose the Test Explorer functionality built-in to VS which I would prefer to be able to use.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google Test programs are normal applications. If you can run your application remotely, why can't you do the same for your tests?

Comment: Yes they are normal applications that target Windows, we are targeting Linux and building/running remotely on Linux. Besides, there is no option in the project properties for a Google Test project to use a remote build machine.

Comment: @cyclic you are right, as of VS version 16.5 there is no integration with the Test Explorer infrastructure in VS for Linux CMake and vcxproj based projects. You may open a Suggestion Ticket at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/suggest-a-feature?view=vs-2019